# Pushing database changes, replication, backup/restore or other...?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario where I receive an update for a database hourly in flat file format. A process, written in c# using EF, updates said database (DB1).

Once the process has ran and was successful I then want to push these changes to another database (DB2), DB2 is essentially copy/mirror of DB1 sans changes.

DB2 is used in a client facing application but it is never updated or modified by a client, however, it must stay online.

Previously the schedule was nightly and this was done by copying and replacing the databases files but now that we need to keep DB1 online at all times I think that rules that out. I was considering replication but it seems like it is potentially overkill and I'm reading it can be a headache and comes with its own host of problems.

The other option would be to run the update process on DB2 that is currently running on DB1 but only after it has successfully ran against DB1?

What is the avenue to investigate first?

Comment: how big are the actual changes in regards to records..? do you know the average..? what about `Triggers, or Bulk Inserts / Updates do you have a `DBA in your organization that can answer this for you..? this screams `DELTA Nightmare` in it's current state..

Comment: No DBA I'm afraid. Number of transactions varies wildly on the current nightly files, I'd say the hourlies could contain anywhere between 10,000 - 1. However, it could be possible that they don't scale like that it could be that one of the hourly files contains 100,000 and the rest only very few.

Comment: have you considered a faster mechanism like Inserting into the other database using `XML bulk Insert`

Comment: I had not, will that be significantly quicker than a traditional process? How would I go about setting it up?